# Chemist package

Tags: packages, chemistry, obsolete

Isn't any longer maintained the `chemist` package ? I don't see it here

https://ctan.org/topic/chemistry

and googling does not provide any recent things. E.g. the [French wiki](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/%C3%89crire_des_formules_chimiques)
talks about a version dated since 2000.

Comment: I've never heard of a package called `chemist` in the entire time I've been using LaTeX: was it ever on CTAN?

Comment: Ah, seems to be part of XymTeX: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xymtex/chemist?lang=en. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @JosephWright This means that it is obsolete? Should I stop use it? Should I use another package? (Thanks for your feedback)

Comment: @dimitris I would check first  `chemfig`,  but what package-s is better  for you depend on what you need exactly.  If `xymtex` is still available and he does  perfectly what you want, why not use it? btw, xymtex was updated in 2013, and it  is not an "obsolete" package. (Obsolete packages as [subfigure](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) have a special stamp).